# Combining non-independent random normal-distributed variables

Tags: random-variables, normal-distribution, sampling

In the below question part b) involves combining normally-distributed random variables which ARE independent.

Part d) involves combining normally-distributed random variables which are NOT independent.

I understand part b) but what is the general approach to solve part d)? Re-write the equation without referring to the sample mean of U?

Question:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Re-write the equation without referring to the sample mean of U?

That's a good idea. $U_1 - \bar{U} = \frac{4}{5} U_1 - \frac{1}{5} (U_2 + \cdots + U_5)$. This is a normal random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\frac{4^2 + 4}{5^2} \sigma^2 = \frac{4}{5}\sigma^2$. Can you then compute $P(U_1 - \bar{U} > \sigma)$?

Comment: I have to confess I know this is the answer for this particular question (I have the mark scheme) but I wanted to understand is this the general technique? i.e. when the variables are NOT independent you always have to eliminate the sample mean?

Comment: @user997112 The importance of independence in this problem is in computing the variance of a sum of random variables: if the random variables are uncorrelated (which is implied if they are independent) then [the variance of the sum is the sum of the variances](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_uncorrelated_variables_(Bienaym%C3%A9_formula)). In (b) and (d) the main work is to rewrite things as sums of independent random variables.